# AngularJS resource call in directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an AngularJS directive that calls a service created using `$resource` with the value of the attribute in the template and makes the result available in the scope of the element.

I have a very simple service:

```
services.factory('Concept', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://example/api/:id');
}]);
```

And a directive:

```
directives.directive('anConcept', ['Concept', function(Concept) {
  return {
    scope: {
      anConcept: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.results = Concept.get({id: concept});
    }
  }
}]);
```

I then try to invoke this in my view:

```
<div an-concept="1">
  {{results}}
</div>
```

Looking at the network pane in my browser's debugger I can see the requests getting made, but the result isn't being made available in the scope of the element.

I'm sure I'm making a very basic mistake but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when you're working with a `$resource`, you're receiving back a promise. Additionally, you may be running into some trouble with the `results` property of your `$scope` if the directive's scope is isolated.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('Concept', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info');
    }
  ])
  .directive('anConcept', ['Concept',
    function(Concept) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controllers) {
          Concept.get({
            site: $attrs.anConcept
          }, function(results) {
            $scope.results = results.items[0].total_users;
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div an-concept="stackoverflow">
    Total stackoverflow users: {{results}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed an isolated scope problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the result of that `get` is a promise. You need to do something like:

```
Concept.get({id: concept}).success(function(data) {
     $scope.results = data;
};
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I think I made a mistake, `$resource` works a bit different then `$http` :

```
Concept.get({id: concept}, function(data) {
     $scope.results = data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see that value out of directive,I will say that you will not see it as a simple.because your directive is ISOLATED-SCOPE directive.It means your values in that scope will be isolated from parent scope and you will not see that value out  of directive(There is a way to get that isolated scope).But if you want to see it in directive,I will say your code is correct code.If response has been accepted,you result will be defined.